# Running a function with the different functionalities at different times in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, redis, task

I'm looking for a way to create a function that takes two args, time and operation and it does the operation at the given time as an argument. The script should be running on a server and it reads the data from a Redis-like database. I'm trying to find a way to do that avoid using any other frameworks or non-standard packages. Have any idea about that?

Answer (score 1):

See the library https://github.com/dbader/schedule and this example https://github.com/dbader/schedule/blob/master/docs/examples.rst#run-a-job-once